# Testing javascript that updates DOM

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am new to web testing and would like to know how can I test javascript that reads and updates the DOM.

```
function otherFunction(string) {
// do some processing and return processed data
}

function domUpdater() {
  var string = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = otherFunction(string);
}
```

I can test easily the otherFunction which accepts and input and returns an output.

```
expect(otherFunction("input1")).to.be("expected1");
expect(otherFunction("input2")).to.be("expected2");
```

I am not clear on how can I test the domUpdater function which modifies the DOM?

Comment: jest https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/

Comment: what do you mean by read and update the DOM? What exactly is the widget you are trying to test? How does the user make use of it?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `jsdom`, and in my case since I'm using mocha it would look like this (using [jsdom-mocha](https://github.com/rstacruz/mocha-jsdom)):

```
var jsdom = require('mocha-jsdom')
var expect = require('chai').expect

describe('mocha tests', function () {

  jsdom()

  it('has document', function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    expect(div.nodeName).eql('DIV')
  })

})
```

However if you can afford it (the tests tend to take a bit longer to run) i would recommend looking into running your tests in a headless browser, using something like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

A quick google search yielded this for [how to run jest with puppeteer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer):

1. First install jest-puppeteer

```
yarn add --dev jest-puppeteer
```

2. Specify preset in your Jest configuration:

```
{
 "preset": "jest-puppeteer"
}
```

3. Write your test

```js
describe('Google', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
  });

  it('should be titled "Google"', async () => {
    await expect(page.title()).resolves.toMatch('Google');
  });
});
```